# What programming languages are used to build Tor?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, source-code

one basic question, I would like to know:

what programming languages are used to build Tor?

TBB include Firefox and other things, so, correct question is about Tor.

Answer (score 5):

Tor itself is C. If you're curious about languages used in the wider ecosystem see...

https://www.torproject.org/getinvolved/volunteer.html.en#Projects

Answer (score 1):

The core Tor library is written mostly in C.

https://www.ohloh.net/p/tor

You can check out the source code yourself here:

https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git